# Need query to figure out when car model name shared by two makes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a simple table with fields make and model.

I'm trying to figure out a query that will tell me when I have a model that is shared by more than 1 make.  That is, if ford and gm both made a car model named "rocket", I want to know that.

I'm using Sql Server but I don't think that really matters.

I made a wild guess of course not right.

```
select make,
   model
group by make,
     model
where count(MODEL) > 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, this will get you the `make` and `model` for each `model` that has more than one `make` if the table `t` consists of unique pairs of `make` and `model`.

```
select make, model
from t
where model in (
  select model
  from t
  group by model
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

If `make` and `model` are not unique pairs for the table, you could use `count(distinct make)` instead:

```
select make, model
from t
where model in (
  select model
  from t
  group by model
  having count(distinct make) > 1
)
```

You could also use an `exists()` query instead of performing aggregation like so:

```
select make, model
from t
where exists (
  select 1
  from t as i
  where i.model=t.model
    and i.make<>t.make
)
```

Comment: The last query executes for me and actually gives me exactly what I wanted!  of my 9000 records, among others, Ford and Plymouth both made a model "Laser".  The first two complain about the where clause in the "in".  Looks right to me though, not sure why.  Thanks!

Comment: @PeterKellner Ahh I made a mistake when I was copying parts of your query, I forgot to change the `where` to `having`. You use `having` when filtering on aggregation functions. Fixed now, and glad I didn't bork all of the options. Glad you got your answer~

Comment: ah.  Now the first two run but the first one shows me a 7106 of my 7275 records (can't be right I think).  Second one does what I expect.

Comment: @PeterKellner The first one would only produce the results you are looking for if "the table `t` consists of unique pairs of `make` and `model` since it is only filtering on the `count(*)` (total rows) per model.

Comment: Thanks @SqlZim.  That makes sense.